# Почему Arduino отправляет лишние символы при общении через COM порт?

Tags: python, arduino, serial

Хотел научить плату arduino UNO c компьютером с помощью python, чтобы потом использовать показания с датчиков, которые снимает arduino и отправляет на COM порт, с которого их обрабатывает python в голосовом помощнике. всё получилось, но вместе с данными отправляются какие-то помехи

пример:

```
b'Hello World\r\n'
```

При том что отправлял просто Hello World. Как убрать эти символы?

вот код для python:

```py
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM20', 9600)
while ("1"):
    print(ser.readline())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

скетч для arduino:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("Hello World");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Это не помехи, это перенос строки в Windows системах. Arduino сама эти символы отправляет, см. [Serial.println()](http://arduino.ru/Reference/Serial/Println).

Comment: но как от них избавиться? иначе помощник будет их проговаривать.

Comment: `ser.readline().rstrip()` - обрежет все `whitespace` символы в конце строки.

Answer (score 4):

`Serial.println` отправляет строку в COM порт и прибавляет символы переноса
Попробуй `Serial.print` без `ln`.

Если всё так-же будет ловить "разграничители", попробуй прописать, чтобы Python их игнорил.

Answer (score 0):

Та-же проблема сегодня была у меня, только пишу на С#, я решил с помощью метода "Contains" в общем он смотрим присутствует ли в пришедших данных в порт с ардуино нужный текст.
      Допустим пришло " b'Hello World\r\n " - с помощью метода можно проверить есть ли тут "Hello World" если да то возвращает true, проверка при помощи if.
На python думаю есть подобное